# Acer Revo (ION platform) + Maverick + 5.1 surround over HDMI

Tags: sound, hdmi

I've had a turbulent relationship with my media centre box. Every upgrade I perform on it seems to bring a brand new set of audio issues (the opposite of my desktop where things seem to get better and better).

It's a Acer Revo 3600. That's basically an low-end Intel Atom chip with a Nvidia 9400M onboard. On paper that's perfect for something like a media centre. But having just upgraded to Maverick, the sound properties box only wants to offer me stereo sound over HDMI.

The exact setup goes: Revo -> Onkyo AV receiver -> LG TV. The Onkyo box strips off the audio (supporting 7.1 -- though we're only using 6 speakers) and feeds the video onto the TV.

I'd like to get to a point where Ubuntu thinks it's doing 5.1 over HDMI, upmixing stereo to 6ch and supporting DTS/AC3 (through Boxee).

I've had this working before but it's frankly been a bit of a hacktastrophe.

The audio chip is recognised as `Nvidia MCP79/7A HDMI` in `alsamixer` if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's first start by making sure you've got updated alsa-lib (**libasound2**) and pulseaudio from maverick-proposed (note: you may have to use a non-updates/proposed kernel for testing).  Next, please see [this link for trying the updated, daily-built sound drivers](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/InstallingLinuxAlsaDriverModules).